# Add to cart button alignment needed on webshop

Tags: php, woocommerce, webshop

On my shop's front page, my products `add to cart` buttons is not aligned.

**See this picture**

[image]

A fix to this would be to just make the titles shorter or make every title be on 2 lines, but that would bring me more problems on my `category pages`.

Is there a way to just fix this here on the front page?

Comment: There're two options, make button's position absolute and bottom 0, don't forget to make li.products position relative. Other option is to give fixed height to title..

Comment: Okay, how do i make the button's position absolute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option #1: Set `position: relative` and optionally a `min-height` on your `li.product` and set `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` on your [Add to cart] buttons in your theme's CSS. Note that your theme may be using different classes/IDs. If the ones I've used don't work, you'll need to inspect with your browser's [inspector tools](https://www.lifewire.com/get-inspect-element-tool-for-browser-756549) to see which to use for your theme:

```
li.product {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 400px; // you may or may not need to set the height 
}

li.product a.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; // combined with right: 0, will center the button
  right: 0; // combined with left: 0, will center the button
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Option #2: Set a `min-height` on your product's title (e.g., `h2`)

```
li.product h2 {
  min-height: 100px; // Adjust to account for your shop's product with the longest title
}
```